# How to use dom_id on non-saved/mock objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, functional-testing

**Note: I'm only posting this question so that others may find it if they ever need to, as I have found a good solution.**

In my controller tests, I don't want to commit to the database, but I still want the controllers to use finder methods to get mock objects (by mocking the `find` method), but then I want to use `dom_id` on those mocks in `assert_select`, to verify that they're being displayed.

However, since they're non-saved objects, `dom_id` keeps returning `new_object` instead of `object_1`, `object_2`, et cetera.

Is there any quick way to get it to work? I really don't want to persist real records in tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you're using `ActiveSupport::TestCase` and `FactoryGirl` for building model objects, you can add this to your `test/test_helper.rb` file:

```
# Generate model with id - useful for assert_select with dom_id
def model(name, options = {})
  @next_id = {} if @next_id.nil?
  @next_id[name] = 1 unless @next_id.has_key(name)

  m = build(name, options)
  m.id = @next_id[name]
  @next_id[name] += 1
  m
end
```

Then, suppose you're using `RR` as your mocking library, you can do something like this:

```
test 'something' do
  posts = [model(:post), model(:post)]
  mock(Post).all { posts }
  get :index
  assert_select "##{dom_id(posts.first)}", posts.first.title
end
```